# is it possible to just login once using Google Calendar APIs v3?

Tags: java, authentication, google-calendar-api

I am developing a desktop application which interacts with Google Calendar. I want user to log in just the first time, so later it will auto login. Can it be done using Google Calendar API v3?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Take a look on the section about refresh tokens